# How to optimize repeating hash in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
  if ENV['ENV'].upcase == 'PROD'
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
        "chromeOptions" => {
            "mobileEmulation" => mobile_emulation,
            "args" => ["headless"]
        })

  elsif (ENV['ENV'].upcase == 'STAGING') || (ENV['ENV'].upcase == 'PR')
    caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
        "chromeOptions" => {
            "mobileEmulation" => mobile_emulation,
            "extensions" => [
                Base64.strict_encode64(File.open("../pf-utils/#{ENV['ENV'].downcase}_basic_auth.crx", 'rb').read)
            ],
            "args" => ["headless"]
        })
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Here, the below entry is newly added,

```
"extensions" => [
            Base64.strict_encode64(File.open("../pf-utils/#{ENV['ENV'].downcase}_basic_auth.crx", 'rb').read)
        ],
```

In such case, how to optimize the above `if...else` statement to avoid repeating code

Comment: You are repeatedly overriding `"args"` key in your hashes. That said, this code does not work as expected and it requires a fix, not an optimization in the first place.

Comment: what if it is not overridden; let me update the question

Comment: I second @mudasobwa here. Before you optimize your code, you need to make it work. Does it work as per your expectation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
options = {
  'chromeOptions' => {
    'mobileEmulation' => mobile_emulation,
    'args' => ['disable-infobars',
               'disable-gpu',
               'disable-extensions',
               'ignore-certificate-errors']
  }
}

if ENV['ENV'].casecmp('PROD').zero?
  options['chromeOptions']['args'].push('headless')
elsif ENV['ENV'].casecmp('STAGING').zero? || ENV['ENV'].casecmp('PR').zero?
  options['chromeOptions']['extensions'] = [
    Base64.strict_encode64(File.open("../pf-utils/#{ENV['ENV'].downcase}_basic_auth.crx", 'rb').read)
  ]
end

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(options)
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: caps
```

Comment: This code is not idempotent. You modify the `options`, making it obviously failing on the subsequent run. Downvoted.

Comment: I assumed that `options` variable is not used anymore, it's only used by `Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome` method

Answer (score 0):

Just declare keys upfront:

```
COMMON_KEYS =
  %w[disable-infobars disable-gpu
     disable-extensions ignore-certificate-errors].freeze
ARGS_KEYS = {
  'STAGING' => COMMON_KEYS + %w[headless],
}.tap { |h| h.default = COMMON_KEYS }.freeze
EXT = {
  'PROD' => {}
}.tap { |h| h.default = {"extensions" => Base64.strict_encode64(...)} }.freeze

caps =
  Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    "chromeOptions" => {
       "mobileEmulation" => mobile_emulation,
       "args" => KEYS[ENV['ENV'].upcase]
    }.merge(EXT)
  }
```

Comment: downvoted because your code missed 'extensions' key to read `*_basic_auth.crx` file, as you see that `extensions` key is an entry that added by him

Comment: @mudasobwa Here, it throws error if the `'STAGING' =>` is not assigned inside `EXT`

Comment: `EXT` hash has a default value, so it’s impossible. Also, when you are reporting “throws an error” it makes sense to mention what error it “is throwing.”

Answer (score 0):

```
extensions =
case ENV['ENV'].upcase
when 'STAGING', 'PR'
  {"extensions" => [Base64.strict_encode64(File.open("../pf-utils/#{ENV['ENV'].downcase}_basic_auth.crx", 'rb').read)]
  }
else {}
end
@driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, desired_capabilities: Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    "chromeOptions" => {
        "mobileEmulation" => mobile_emulation,
        "args" => ["headless"]
    }.merge(extensions))
```

Comment: downvoted because extensions could be nil, when ENV doesn't match with PROD nor STAGING, PR, so Hash#merge will raise TypeError because when extensions variable equal nil

Comment: @SaiqulHaq The OP's code will raise an error as well when `ENV` is neither `PROD`, `STAGING`, nor `PR` since `caps` is not defined in such case, which implies that `ENV` is in fact neither `PROD`, `STAGING`, nor `PR`. Your comment and down vote are invalid.

Comment: @mudasobwa Thanks for editing the answer to make it comply with such case anyway.

Comment: A variant; replace `}.merge(extensions)` with `}.merge(ENV['ENV'].match?( /\ASTAGING|PR/i) ? ("extensions" => [Base64....read)])  : {})`.

Comment: @SaiqulHaq, if your objection has been addressed please consider removing your downvote. btw, regardless of whether I think your downvote was justified, kudos for owning up to it. I detest silent downvotes, SO's "hit and runs".